# Ubuntu Server 20.04 Crashes when using premade MBR partitons

Tags: server, 20.04, mbr, xen, subiquity

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu on 150GB MBR disk with 3 partitions

```
/boot 1GiB
swap  8GiB
/     140.9GiB
```

The moment the installer starts the format it crashes. Does anyone know what might be the issue?

The disk must remain MBR as part of requirement as I'm using older xenserver hypervisor. It feels like Subiquity is an overall downgrade compared to old debian installer which just worked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: Looking further found that the flag for swap is seen as none by the installer. Not sure what's causing it as it's set correctly in fdisk.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure 100MB is sufficient for boot

Comment: I am sure 100 MB is not enough. Probably OP mixed up with EFI.

Comment: Hmm, trying with 1GiB

Comment: It still crashes exactly same way @Pilot6

Comment: The more I'm tinkering with it the more it looks like a Subiquity bug.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely a Subiquity bug, thanks for filing it.  [(LP: #1952545)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/1952545)

Based on the requirement for the MBR partition table and current Subiquity behaviors, I can picture two possible workarounds

- During install, leave space at the end of the disk, and add the swap partition manually during first boot

OR

- Format the drive for 2 partitions, include the space for the swap in the `/` partition, and add a swap file to the `/` partition after install is complete